# Parameters is null - in Facebook toolkit

Tags: visualforce, facebook, parameters

I am using facebook toolkit for posting on fan page and wall of facebook. I am calling the VF page from a custom button. When i click on the custom button on record the id of the record is passed with the url of the VF page. The VF page have the controller FacebookFavoriteController and it is extended from FacebookLoginController which is the part of the toolkit. and in the VF page `action="{!login}"` is called from FacebookLoginController class. At the first time when VF page get loaded i ma getting the parameter from the url. After the login method is called in FacebookLoginController class it comes back for further process the parameter is null.

The reason i get the null value is because, the redirect url set in the facebook application is `https://xxxxx--c.cs5.visual.force.com/apex/FacebookFavoritePage` this does not have the parameter called id in the url. Is there a way to maintain the state of jobID once the oauth procedure is completed.

The url when the first loaded before login method is executed.
`https://xxxxx--c.cs5.visual.force.com/apex/FacebookFavoritePage?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

FacebookFavoriteController class :

```
global with sharing class FacebookFavoriteController extends FacebookLoginController {

public static String getAccessToken() {
    return FacebookToken.getAccessToken();
}

public Id jobID {get; set;}// Get the ID from URL
public CMSR__Position__c posDetails {get; set;}// The SOQL result on the base for jobId
public String siteUrl {get;set;} // Site Url
public String acctok {get; set;}// access token 
//public Cookie jobId_cookie;

//costructor 
public FacebookFavoriteController(){
    posDetails = new CMSR__Position__c();
    jobID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); // Getting the jobId from URL    

    positionDetails();
}

public void positionDetails(){
    system.debug('JOB ID ' + jobID);
    //jobId_cookie = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get(jobID);
    system.debug('Cookie ' + jobId_cookie);
    if(jobID != null){
        posDetails = [SELECT Name, CMSR__Linked_In_Url__c, CMSR__Departments__c, CMSR__Responsibilities__c, CMSR__Required_Qualifications_and_Skills__c, CMSR__Summary__c, CMSR__Job_Description__c, CMSR__Job_Type__c, CMSR__Location__c, CMSR__Location_State__c, CMSR__Max_years_of_Exp__c, CMSR__Min_Years_of_Exp__c, CMSR__Skills_Required__c FROM CMSR__Position__c WHERE Id=:jobID];
    }

    CMSR__Sites_address__c sa = CMSR__Sites_address__c.getInstance('Site url');    
    siteUrl = sa.CMSR__Site__c+'/apex/CMSR__PositionDetail?id='+jobID;
    system.debug('site url ' + siteUrl);
}

public FacebookUser me {
    get {
        // Can't set up 'me' in the controller constructor, since the 
        // superclass 'login' method won't have been called!
        if (me == null) {
            String accessToken = getAccessToken();

            // If accessToken is null, it's likely that the page's action 
            // method has not yet been called, so we haven't been to FB to
            // get an access token yet. If this is the case, we can just 
            // leave 'me' as null, since the redirect will happen before
            // HTML is sent back.
            if (accessToken != null) {
                me = new FacebookUser(accessToken, 'me');                    
            }
        }

        return me;
    } set;
}

public Integer favorite {
    get {
        /* if (favorite == null) { */
            String accessToken = getAccessToken();
            acctok = accessToken;
            if (accessToken != null) {
                List<Facebook_Favorite__c> favorites = 
                    [SELECT Favorite_Number__c
                        FROM Facebook_Favorite__c
                        WHERE Facebook_ID__c = :me.id];

             /*   favorite = (favorites.size() == 0) ? 
                    null : 
                    Integer.valueOf(favorites[0].Favorite_Number__c);*/
            }
       /* }*/

        return favorite;
    } set;
}

private FacebookUsers friends { 
    get {
        if (friends == null) {
            String accessToken = getAccessToken();

            if (accessToken != null) {
                Map<String, String> params = 
                    new Map<String, String>{'fields' => 'id,name'};
                friends = new FacebookUsers(accessToken, 'me/friends', params);
            }
        }

        return friends;
    } set;
}

public List<Facebook_Favorite__c> friendsFavorites {
    get {
        if (friendsFavorites == null) {
            String accessToken = getAccessToken();

            if (accessToken != null) {
                List<String> friendIDs = new List<String>();

                // Show my own favorite number, if I have one
                friendIDs.add(me.id);    

                for (FacebookUser friend : friends.data) {
                    friendIDs.add(friend.id);
                }

                friendsFavorites = [SELECT Name, Facebook_ID__c, Favorite_Number__c
                    FROM Facebook_Favorite__c
                    WHERE Facebook_ID__c IN :friendIDs
                    ORDER BY Favorite_Number__c DESC];
            }
        }

        return friendsFavorites;
    } set;
}

public PageReference save(){
    if (me == null) {
        throw new FacebookException('Cannot save without a Facebook user!');
    }

    List<Facebook_Favorite__c> favorites = 
        [SELECT Favorite_Number__c
            FROM Facebook_Favorite__c
            WHERE Facebook_ID__c = :me.id];

    if (favorites.size() == 0) {
        Facebook_Favorite__c newFavorite = new Facebook_Favorite__c(Name = me.name, 
            Facebook_ID__c = me.id, 
            Favorite_Number__c = favorite);
        insert newFavorite;
    } else {
        favorites[0].Favorite_Number__c = favorite;
        update favorites[0];
    }

    // Force the favorites list to be refreshed so I see my own favorite
    friendsFavorites = null;

    return null;
}

public PageReference refreshFriendsFavorites() {
    // Force the friends list to be refreshed
    friends = null;

    // Force the favorites list to be refreshed
    friendsFavorites = null;

    return null;
}    
  }
```

FacebookLoginController class:

```
 public virtual class FacebookLoginController {
 // Return a default - the first FB app we find - this will be fine for 
 // many cases but can be overridden in subclasses if there are multiple 
 // FB apps in the org 
 public virtual String getAppId() {
    List<FacebookApp__c> fapps = [SELECT clientID__c FROM FacebookApp__c];
    if ( fapps.size() == 0 ) {
        throw new FacebookException('No FacebookApp__c records found. '+
            'Do you need to go and create one?');
    }
    return fapps[0].clientID__c;
}

public virtual PageReference login() {
    List<FacebookApp__c> fapps = [SELECT clientID__c, clientSecret__c, permissions__c 
        FROM FacebookApp__c 
        WHERE clientID__c = :getAppId()];

    if ( fapps.size() == 0 ) {
        throw new FacebookException('No FacebookApp__c record found for app id '+getAppId()+
           '. Do you need to go and create one?');
    }

    // Get a URL for the page without any query params    

    String url = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().split('\\?')[0];        
    //String url = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl();
    if( (ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().split('\\?')).size() > 0 ){
        string param = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().split('\\?')[1];
        system.debug('param url ' + param);
    }
    System.debug('url is '+url);

    // note: connect url in fb application connect setting should be: https://c.na3.visual.force.com/apex/
    // you need the trailing slash even though it bitches about it
    String rediruri = 'https://'+ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')+url;

    System.debug('rediruri is:'+rediruri);

    String sessionId = FacebookToken.getAccessToken();

    if (sessionId != null) {
        // Check that we can access FB
        try {
            FacebookUtil.get(sessionId, 'me', new Map<String, String>{'fields' => 'id'});
        } catch (FacebookException e) {
            System.Debug('Expired access token? '+e.getMessage());
            FacebookToken.deleteAccessToken();
            sessionId = null;
        }
    }

    System.debug('sessionid='+sessionId);
    if (sessionId != null) {
        // All done                
        return null;
    }

    // No session
    String exPerms = (fapps[0].permissions__c != null && fapps[0].permissions__c != '') ?
        ('&scope='+fapps[0].permissions__c.replace(';', ',')) : '';
    PageReference pageRef;

    if (! ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('code')) {
        // Initial step of OAuth - redirect to FB OAuth service
        System.debug('Facebook OAuth Step 1');

        String authuri = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='+
                        fapps[0].clientID__c+'&redirect_uri='+rediruri+exPerms;

        pageRef = new PageReference(authuri);
    } else {
        // Second step of OAuth - get token from FB OAuth service
        String code = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');

        System.debug('Facebook OAuth Step 2 - code:'+code);

        String authuri = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='+
                        fapps[0].clientID__c+'&redirect_uri='+rediruri+exPerms+
                        '&client_secret='+FacebookCrypto.decrypt(fapps[0].clientSecret__c)+'&code='+code;                    
        System.debug('authuri is:'+authuri);

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(authuri);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(60*1000);

        Http h = new Http();
        String resp;
        if (code.equals('TEST')) {
            resp = 'access_token=TEST&expires=3600';
        } else {
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            resp = res.getBody();
        }

        System.debug('FINAL RESP IS:'+resp); 

        FacebookToken.setAccessToken(resp);

        // Come back to this page without the code param
        // We need to do this to commit the DML before any callouts
        //
        // Note the dummy parameter - this is required because FB
        // puts #_ on the end of the URL, which seems to confuse VF -
        // we get %23_ appended to the url after the redirect. Adding 
        // a dummy parameter means that the VF page name is not 
        // corrupted - the parameter takes the hit and ends up as 
        // a=b%23_ :-)
        pageRef = new PageReference(url+'?a=b');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    }

    return pageRef;
}

static testMethod void testController() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.FacebookSamplePage;

    // We'll need the URL later to check we're being redirected to 
    // the right place
    String url = pageRef.getUrl().split('\\?')[0];

    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    FacebookLoginController controller = new FacebookLoginController();

    PageReference nextPageRef = controller.login();

    // Did we get redirected to FB?
    System.assert(nextPageRef.getUrl().startsWith('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize'));

    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    pageRef.getParameters().put('code', 'TEST');

    nextPageRef = controller.login();

    // Did we get redirected back to the page?
    System.assertEquals(nextPageRef.getUrl(), url+'?a=b');
    System.assert(nextPageRef.getRedirect());
}
 }
```

Vf page :

```
<apex:page controller="FacebookFavoriteController" action="{!login}" 
   cache="false" sidebar="false" title="Facebook Favorite Number">
<div id='fb-root'></div>

<script src='https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js' />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<apex:pageBlock title="Welcome, {!me.name}!">
    <!-- Collect a favorite number from the user -->
    <!-- <apex:form >
        <apex:outputLabel >Enter your favorite number:</apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText value="{!favorite}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form> -->
    <br/>
    <!-- Only show the 'Share' button if the user has entered a favorite -->
    <!-- <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(favorite))}"> -->
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:form >
            <table >
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Name :"></apex:outputLabel></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!posDetails.Name}" /><br/>
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Summary :"></apex:outputLabel></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!posDetails.CMSR__Summary__c}" style="width:350px;"/><br/>
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Job Description :"></apex:outputLabel></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!posDetails.CMSR__Job_Description__c}" style="width:350px;"/>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:form>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" 
            onclick="postToFeed(); return false;" 
            value="Share with Friends"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" 
            onclick="postToPage(); return false;" 
            value="Share On Page"/>
        <p id='msg'></p>





        <script> 
          FB.init({appId: '{!appId}', status: true, cookie: true});


          function postToPage() {
          var page_id = '1426984900889247';
          FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
            if(resp.access_token) {
                FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
                    'post',
                    { message: "{!posDetails.Name}",
                      description :'{!posDetails.CMSR__Job_Description__c}',
                      link : '{!siteUrl}',
                      picture: '{!posDetails.CMSR__Linked_In_Url__c}',
                      caption: '{!posDetails.CMSR__Summary__c}',
                      access_token: resp.access_token }
                     ,function(response) {
                     console.log(response);
                     });
                }
            });
            alert(resp);
         }

          function postToFeed() {
            var obj = {
              method: 'feed',
              link: '{!siteUrl}',
              picture: '{!posDetails.CMSR__Linked_In_Url__c}',
              name: '{!posDetails.Name}',
              caption: '{!posDetails.CMSR__Summary__c}',
              description: '{!posDetails.CMSR__Job_Description__c}'
            };

            function callback(response) {
                if (response['post_id']) {
                    var postId = response['post_id'].split('_')[1];
                    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 
                        "Posted to your wall. "+
                        "<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?"+
                        "id={!me.id}&v=wall&story_fbid="+postId+"\">View your post</a>";
                }
            }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
          }
        </script>



        <script>

            $( document ).ready(function() {

                FB.api('/me/accounts',  function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    alert("Error: " + response.error.message);

                })

            });            
        </script>


    </apex:outputPanel>
    <br />


    <!-- 
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Your Friends' Favorite Numbers" 
        columns="2" id="friendsFaves">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!friendsFavorites}" var="fave">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        /* Link to each friend's Facebook page */
                        <apex:outputLink target="_new" 
                            value="https://www.facebook.com/{!fave.Facebook_ID__c}">
                            {!fave.Name}
                        </apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!fave.Favorite_Number__c}" 
                        headerValue="Favorite Number"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <br/>
                <apex:actionStatus startText="Updating List" 
                    stopText="Click Refresh to update friends list" 
                    id="friendsStatus"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            /* Blank section item so Refresh button is rendered below list */
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:form >
                <apex:commandButton value="Refresh" 
                    action="{!refreshFriendsFavorites}" 
                    rerender="friendsFaves" status="friendsStatus"/>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
         -->
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Please guide me to get the solution for this issue.